# CodeIgniter Get URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

On one of my pages, I am checking if the user has permissions:

```
// Validate our user
if ($this->global_model->get_permission() != 'Admin') 
{
    redirect('/permissions/index/'.current_url());
}
```

On the permissions controller, I am logging where they came from:

```
$this->global_model->log_data('permission','Invalid Permissions | Referer : ' . $this->uri->segment(3));
```

Due to the URL having `/` in it, its giving me `http:` as URI3.

How can I pass this in the URL but get the whole value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a workaround like this to avoid splitting up the URI:

```
redirect('/permissions/index/' . base64_encode(current_url()) );
```

Then on the other usage (the parameter next to the method name):

```
$url = base64_decode($this->uri->segment(3));
$this->global_model->log_data('permission','Invalid Permissions | Referer : ' . $url);
```

Comment: Cool, that worked for me! I had to add an `=` to `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` hope that's not a big issue..

Comment: @SBB oh yes i forgot about that, its included in one of the filters of CI, im glad this helped